# Calculate to and fro track distance in leaflet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, leaflet

I am using leaflet-rails gem (0.7.4) and I need to calculate track distance in case the path is to and fro. In our application, we upload GPX file and display the points using leaflet. We calculate the track distance by first and last point but in case of to and fro path this track distance comes out to zero. Here `points` is an array of coordinates (latitude and longitude).

```
def deg2rad deg
  return deg * Math::PI / 180;
end

def fetch_track_distance
 distance = 0
 start_point = self.points.first
 end_point = self.points.last

 if start_point.present? && end_point.present?
  dLat = self.deg2rad(end_point.latitude - start_point.latitude)
  dLon = self.deg2rad(end_point.longitude - start_point.longitude)

  r = Math::sin(dLat/2) *
    Math::sin(dLat/2) +
    Math::cos(self.deg2rad(start_point.latitude)) *
    Math::cos(self.deg2rad(end_point.latitude)) *
    Math::sin(dLon/2) *
    Math::sin(dLon/2);
  c = 2 * Math::atan2(Math.sqrt(r), Math::sqrt(1-r));
  mdist = RADIAN * c;
  distance = (mdist/1000) if mdist.present?
 end

 return distance.round(3)
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is ruby code. Are you trying to accomplish this on the backend or frontend? Your title indicates you want to do it in Leaflet. You do know Leaflet has tools for calculating distance between points correct?(http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng-distanceto)

Comment: backend. yes, i know there are tools provided by leaflet but in case of to and fro path i am not getting the correct distance. I was thinking of using leaflet-gpx plugin but i am not storing the GPX file on my server. Also i would prefer leaflet-rails over any other plugin.